# Javascript implementing callbacks whenever object property is changed

Tags: javascript

I need something that callbacks whenever a object property is changed, akin to Object.watch and Object.observe. However, those are not cross browser yet.

I need to support the following:

1. supports multiple watches on the same property on
   the same object
2. it must not mutate the object
3. there must be a way to cancel a specific watch without affecting others.

I implemented the following which met criteria 1) and 2) but not 3):

```
/**
 * Add getter/setter to the obj so that the callback is called whenever the property value is changed
 * Returns a function that cancels the watch
 * @param {object} obj
 * @param {string} prop
 * @param {function} callback
 * @return {function}
 */
function watch(obj,prop,callback){
    if (obj[prop]===undefined || !obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        throw new Error("Dangerous use of watch, "+obj+" does not have ["+prop+"]");
    }
    var prevState = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj,prop);
    var _var = obj[prop];

    Object.defineProperty(obj,prop,{
        set: prevState.set === undefined ?
            function(value){
                _var = value;
                callback(value);
            }
            :
            function(value){
                prevState.set(value);
                callback(prevState.get());
            },
        get: prevState.get === undefined ?
            function(){
                return _var;
            }
            :
            function(){
                return prevState.get();
            }
    });

    return function cancelWatch(){
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj,prop));
        var val = obj[prop];
        delete obj[prop];
        if (prevState.get !== undefined || prevState.set !== undefined){
            Object.defineProperty(obj,prop,{
                get: prevState.get,
                set: prevState.set
            })
        } else {
            obj[prop] = val;
        }
    };
}
```

For example; this works:

```
var o = {};
o.a = 1;

var c0 = watch(o,"a",function(v){console.log("watch: "+v)});
var c1 = watch(o,"a",function(v){console.log("watch: "+v)});

> o.a = 5;
"watch 5"
"watch 5"
```

However, the problem is in the cancelling. If I call c1(), all is fine because it just pops its getter/setter off. However, if I call c0, that doesn't work because it resets the getter/setter state to before the first watch is called, and thus eliminating the second watch from triggering. My question is, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing it on your own you should try to find and use existing shims (just google for "Object.observe shim")

Nevertheless I tried to fix your code: http://jsbin.com/jupuro/2/edit?js,console

Comment: I have looked into them but they use polling to accomplish this functionality (ie, with setInterval and comparing values) whereas I need a solution that fires the moment the property is changed. That being said I do like your solution.

Comment: I have updated the version in my anwer because there was an error if you used watch an object with already custom defined properties..